# Pass an input variable and loop it in here document bash script

Tags: bash, heredoc

I am trying to solve an issue which is i need to pass user input to here document and loop its value. I am able to only one thing at time, either pass variable or loop. Both are not working.

Below is my code.

```
bash <<START
echo "Input :$1"
for i in 1 2 3 4 5
do
echo "For Loop Value : $i"
done
START
```

While running this script ./heredoc "asd" im am getting below output

```
Input :asd
For Loop Value :
For Loop Value :
For Loop Value :
For Loop Value :
For Loop Value :
```

As you can see the value of i is not coming.

But if i add single quote it gives below output.

```
Input :
For Loop Value :1
For Loop Value :2
For Loop Value :3
For Loop Value :4
For Loop Value :5
```

How can i solve it so that my input value as well as loop value should come in output.

Thanks in advance

Comment: tried bash <<'START' but in that case i am loosing my user input variable value as mentioned in post..Thanks anyway.

Comment: Oh, sorry! then escape the expansions: `echo "For Loop Value : \$i"`

Comment: "gniourf_gniourf" you are genius..thanks..that worked...

Comment: Now the real question is _why are you using a heredoc like so in the first place?_

Comment: Here is the real question. 
"sudo -u vinay bash <<EOF
echo "Input value after SUDO $1"
IFS=';' read -ra ADDR <<<"$1"
for i in "${ADDR[@]}";
do
        echo "\$i"
done

echo "end"
EOF
"
it should print input value. so if i give input "asd;qwe;zxc" it should print 
asd
qwe
zxc

But its not printing:(.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not passing anything.  `$1` will be the first positional parameter of the running shell, probably an empty string.

This will do what you want:

```
variable="hello there"

bash <<SCRIPT_END
echo "Input: $variable"
for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do
    echo "For Loop Value: \$i"
done
SCRIPT_END
```

You will have to escape the `$i` in the here-document as it would otherwise be interpolated with the value of any variable `i` in the current environment (an empty string if unset).

Note that you *do* want this to happen for `$variable` (what you call "passing to the here-document") and that's why we can't just single-quote the whole thing (by changing the first `SCRIPT_END` to `'SCRIPT_END'`).